# What is the max hostname length on Solaris 8/10? And can it be expanded?

Tags: unix, ipv6

I found getconf HOST_NAME_MAX to return 255 on my Sol 10 box, so I'm assuming that that is the max length of a hostname in Solaris 10. Can this be expanded? What about for ipv6?

Answer (score 2):

The length of a hostname is not related to IP at all. It's a *name*, so only name resolution protocols matter. DNS, for example, limits the length of a single *label* (dot-separated part) to [63 characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1034#section-3.1) and the length of a full domain name to 253 characters.

---

Either way, if you *do* need a hostname longer than 255 bytes, you have bigger problems.